# Mathematical prerequisites for Glimm and Jaffe?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, education

I am trying to get a better formal understanding of QFT and people have recommended Glimm and Jaffe 'Quantum Physics a Functional Integral Point of View'  Particularly as it uses Euclidean path integrals and my PhD is in lattice qft.

However I feel I am not up to speed with the maths to see why the definitions and subtleties are important.  What maths is required for this book, and do people have any recommendations on resources for them?

Comment: A more recent book which should be more accessible is "Quantum Mechanics and Quantum Field Theory, A Mathematical Primer" by Dimock. https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/quantum-mechanics-and-quantum-field-theory/06B6B13B344880D492F4A09C9C1E713D

Comment: Reed & Simon books, especially the volume 1, are the mathematical prerequisites, I believe.